# A Java program to get roll from user and there it is giving an error while compiling the code as marking to School object

Tags: java

I have written a code in java-

```
public class school
{
int rollno;

public void setRollno(int r)
{
rollno = r;
}
public int getRollno(int r)
return roll no;
}
}
class enca
{
Public static void main (String []args)
{
School sc = new School();
sc.setRollno();
System.out.println(sc.getRollno());

}
}
```

A Java program to get roll from user and there it is giving an error while compiling the code as marking to School object

There is error in School object ...
So how do I solve it?

Comment: Firstly, `getRollno()` is a getter - it should not be accepting any input. Secondly, `roll no` inside `getRollno()` is a typo.

Comment: You should include the error you're getting, that way people can help you learn to read the error message too.

Answer (score 1):

I see multiple errors in the current code given.

1. your class name is "school" but then when creating the sc object you used "School"
2. getRollno is missing its opening flower bracket and also returns "roll no" instead of "rollno" and is also accepting input for some reason
3. in the main method, you said sc.setRollno() without inputting any arguments, even though it is expecting a rollno
4. for public static void main, you maid your public capitalized as "Public" instead of "public"

also, I recommend using tabs when creating your code because it makes it readable for not just yourself but also for others reading your code

Answer (score 0):

agree with @slayerofthend

and this is the answer u need maybe. u can compare with urs.

```
public class Enca {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        School sc = new School();
        sc.setRollno(1);
        System.out.println(sc.getRollno());
    }
    
    public static class School {
        int rollno;

        public void setRollno(int r) {
            rollno = r;
        }

        public int getRollno() {
            return rollno;
        }
    }
    
}
```